# Generate number line automatic using Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm working in one project that users create sale, in sale the users want to add some product, product are in array, these product submit in the table. In this table I want to have and id unique for row product. The name of this id is line_num and I can post in ws with all Products array. My question is: How to generate automatic this line_num for my product? For example, number array+1 is line_num.

This is one array products. This `"Line_num":2` I want to generate automatic for each line

```
[{"product_id":"11E822EF6E70F36EB430FA163EBBBC1D","Product_type_id":"11E7FC041F467AD4B09D00FF76874A58","Line_num":2,"Description":"dgdf","Quantity":3,"Unit_price":34,"Subtotal":102}]
```

Can you suggest me how to implement in Typescript code?

Thank you

Comment: Don't you save your data in a database ? (postgres, mysql etc..)

Comment: Yes I send, but I want to have a line_num for each product, because each sale should have the product and the line where that product is located. check array Products

Comment: Do not store line_num, always refer to the uniq id. For example you may want to filter products in the future, and your line_num will not correspond to the display.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure i got the problem, but if you have a data from db and model, you can easily push another field to it like that:

```
this.products.forEach((product, index) => {
  const id = {'line_num': index};
  Object.assign(product, id);
});
```